# Interchanging lim and log

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, logarithms

Suppose I have a n-dependent function $f_n(X,Y)$, and I have the following result

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \ln\left( f_n(X,Y)\right) = g(X,Y)
$$

From this, can we deduce that $f_n(X,Y) = \exp( n g(X,Y))$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: $a_n=b_n$ as $n \to \infty$ is not a meaningful statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about pointwise limits, we have that
$$
\lim \frac 1n \ln(f_n(x,y)) = \lim \ln (f_n(x,y)^{1/n}) = \ln \left( \lim (f_n(x,y)^{1/n})\right)
$$

So, what you can say is

$$
\lim f_n(x,y)^{1/n} = e^{g(x,y)}.
$$

*Note*: the interchange between $\ln$ and $\lim$ is justified by the continuity of the logarithm function.

Comment: I think you ought to justify the second equality by murmuring "by the continuity of $\ln$".

Comment: Thanks! In the first line, how are we allowed to interchange limit and log in the second equality

Comment: @Rostam22 If you consider Heine's definition of continuity, you can understand very clearly that the limit can be interchanged with any continuous function.

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are right, I'll add to my answer.